# Recent https (SSL) addition, getting site cannot provide secure connection error page

Tags: ssl, https

Recently our website went from http to https. I, and others, are randomly getting "The Site Can't Provide a Secure Connection" page. Upon refresh, the page loads just fine. Why are we getting this initial page randomly?

FYI... We have http to https redirects in place.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say without more details, but some things I can suggest are:

1. You have multiple servers and some are configured correctly and some incorrectly.
2. You are not including the full certificate chain. Sometimes your browser has the missing intermediary cached and sometimes not (see this answer for more info here: https://serverfault.com/questions/826100/ca-certificate-trouble-with-squid-on-centos7/826321#826321)
3. A bug in browser/software. I had this issue on Chrome when using Apache HTTP/2. Never did figure it out but a Chrome update fixed it.

Run https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ on your site to confirm not a problem with your https set up and, if that doesn't work, or you don't understand the results it gives, then update your question with more details (what Server and Browser you are using and what version, if you have any proxy in place between your Browser and the site and, ideally the website name) if you want people to help you.

Also be aware this is a programming site and some people don't like these questions here and will suggest other Stack Exchange sites but honestly don't know where this question is best placed: serverfault.com maybe, but is for professional SysAdmins only, Unix and Linux seems a little generic (not even sure if you are using a Linux webserver!), Webmasters is more for content and SEO questions, Information and Security is more for theoretical SSL/TLS questions...